# Dynamic render view symfony5

Tags: php, html, symfony, web, routes

I tried to do an dynamic render view in my website with dynamic url.
I tried to write an function to do that.

```
    public function html(Name $formation, string $slug, Html $name): Response
    {
        if($formation->getSlug() !== $slug){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('html', [
                'id' => $formation->getId(),
                'slug' => $formation->getSlug(),
                'name' => $name->getName()
            ], 301);


        }
        return $this->render('html_css/'.$name.'.html.twig');
    }
```

All stuffs is in a database but when I tried to return the render `$name` got an issues :
(Method '__toString' is not implemented for '\App\Entity\Html') but $name is an string

```
    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

So why I have this issues ?

Do you thinks they are better solution to do what I want ?
I try to search on routing documentation of symfony but don't find what I wan't.

Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need:

```
return $this->render('html_css/' . $name->getName() . '.html.twig');
```

Because `$name` is instance of `Html` and **not a string**.